# erlang how to get time with microsecond

Tags: erlang

Im trying to get timein the following format "2015-04-13T17:37:46.456Z"

I am using the below function to get it :

```
get_time({_,_,Micro} = Timestamp) ->
    {{Year, Month, Day}, {Hour, Minute, Second}} =     calendar:now_to_datetime(Timestamp),
    StrTime = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~4..0w-~2..0w-~2..0wT~2..0w:~2..0w:~2..0w.~3..0wZ",[Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second,Micro])),
    StrTime.
```

However, when I call this function it returns something like this : "2015-04-13T17:37:46.***Z"
it displays *(asterisks) in the place of microsecond. What wrong am I doing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [io manual](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html) If the field width specified is too small, then the whole field will be filled with * characters. For Micro seconds the field width is spcified as 3 but it can be 6 digits which is resulting in *.

You can convert the Microseconds to string and then use first 3 characters with leading 0 if less than 3 digits.

```
    lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~4..0w-~2..0w-~2..0wT~2..0w:~2..0w:~2..0w.~3..0sZ",
[Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, integer_to_list(Micro)])).
```

Comment: I need it to be 3 digits. Does integer_to_list converts Microsecond to string ? I tried the exact same code that you provided but still getting *.

Comment: Yes integer_to_list converts integer to string. Are you sure you tried the exact code above with s instead of w? I am getting the proper values

Comment: ahh my bad.. didnt see that change you made... its working now.. thanks mate!

Comment: This will not work when you sample a time with a value for microsecond less than 100000.

Comment: ~3..0s will add leading 0s. integer_to_list(trunc(Micro/1000)) will give the proper milliseconds. Here is an example. lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~3..0s",[integer_to_list(trunc(1234/1000))])). Output: "001"

Answer (score 1):

You are asking to print the micro second with only 3 digit while it needs 6 (in general) to be printed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need it to be 3 digits. How may I fix this ?

Comment: With 3 digit you can only print millisecond ! (1000 millisec per second). you can replace Micro by (Micro div 1000). If you want also µsec, you must add a field and you get the µsec with (Micro rem 1000).

Comment: I tried dividing it by 1000 and then round() it. It worked pretty well. but whats gonna happen when the microsecond part is less than 6 digits. I wont get three digits after dividing then. Will it add a leading zero or is there others ways to address this ?

Comment: If you do: StrTime = `lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~4..0w-~2..0w-~2..0wT~2..0w:~2..0w:~2..0w.~3..0wZ",[Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second,Micro div 1000]))` you will get what you want